# 5 arrays Union MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

I have to write a program . It takes max 5 char arrays from input, (char by char, the char '0' is used to and the sequence) print them, and print union and intersection array. 
I'm having some problem writing the function that creates the Union array. This is the code I wrote. (Mind char '0' is present in all the arrays the program creates, but I'm trying to not insert any '0' in union array.)

```
unite: # PARAM baseaddressvetUnione= $a1, baseAddressvectorToUn=$a2, v.length=$a3)

move $t2, $zero                  # int i=0, 


forIparte1:
beq $t2, $a3, uscitaUnione       # se i==v.length ha finito e torna al main

lbu $t0, 0($a1)                  # v[i] = $t0
beq $t0, $s0, updateForI         # v[i] == 0, not considers this element

move $t3, $zero                  # int j=0

forJ:
blt $s3, $t3, forIparte2         # if k < j exit from j loop

lbu $t1, 0($a2)                  # unione[j] = $t1
beq $t0, $t1, updateForI         # if v[i]==unione[j], it doesn't store v[i]

addi $a2, $a2, 1                 # 
addi $t3, $t3, 1                 # j++

j forJ

forIparte2:
sb $t0, vettoreUnione($s3)       # vettoreUnione[k] = v[i]
addi $s3, $s3, 1                 # k++

beq $s2, $s3, printUnione        # if 49==k (vettoreUnione is full) go to print

updateForI:
addi $a1, $a1, 1                 # incremento il puntatore a v[i]
addi $t2, $t2, 1                 # i++
j forIparte1

uscitaUnione:
jr $ra
```

Comment: "Some problem". What error does your code produce? Does it fail to compile? Fail to run?

Comment: any error, the program just loops after printing "Union Array: ["